# Spring web app - Hibernate can't catch PersistenceException

Tags: spring, hibernate

I've web application with

Hibernate 5.1
JPA 2.1
Spring 4

When i try to delete a record, that's referred in other table, i get a 500 internal error. I cannot catch exception

error

```
HTTP Status 500 - Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint [null]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
```

function code in dao

```
    public void delete(Integer id){
    status = false;
    try {
        PlantEntity pe = findById(id);

        if (pe != null) {
            entityManager.remove(pe);
            message = "Record rimosso con successo.";
            status = true;
        } else {
            message = "Record non trovato.";
        }
    }catch(DataIntegrityViolationException ex2) {
        message = ex2.getMessage();
    }catch(PersistenceException exSql){
        message = exSql.getMessage();
    }catch(RuntimeException ex){
        message = ex.getMessage();
    }
}
```

function code in controller

```
package it.webgate.controller;

import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.*;

import com.google.gson.Gson;
import it.webgate.collections.*;
import it.webgate.dao.*;
import it.webgate.form.ActivityForm;
import it.webgate.model.*;
import it.webgate.service.Configuration;
import it.webgate.service.WebGateUtils;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;
import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile;
import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartHttpServletRequest;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

import javax.annotation.Resource;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/ajax/")
@Component
public class AjaxController {

    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(AjaxController.class);


    @Resource
    private  PlantDao plantDao;


    @Resource
    private Configuration configuration;

    @PersistenceContext
    EntityManager entityManager;

    @Resource
    private ActivityDao activityDao;


    @Transactional(rollbackFor = Exception.class)
    @RequestMapping(value = "/plant-delete", headers = "Accept=application/json")
    public Object plantDelete(@RequestParam Integer id){
        Map<String,Object> out = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        try{
            plantDao.delete(id);
            out.put("status",plantDao.getStatus());
            out.put("message",plantDao.getMessage());
        }catch(Exception e){
            out.put("status",false);
            out.put("message",plantDao.getMessage());
        }
        return out;
    }

    public EntityManager getEntityManager() {
        return entityManager;
    }

    public void setEntityManager(EntityManager entityManager) {
        this.entityManager = entityManager;
    }
}
```

full stack trace

```
    HTTP Status 500 - Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.transaction.TransactionSystemException: Could not commit JPA transaction; nested exception is javax.persistence.RollbackException: Transaction marked as rollbackOnly

type Exception report

message Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.transaction.TransactionSystemException: Could not commit JPA transaction; nested exception is javax.persistence.RollbackException: Transaction marked as rollbackOnly

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.transaction.TransactionSystemException: Could not commit JPA transaction; nested exception is javax.persistence.RollbackException: Transaction marked as rollbackOnly
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:979)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:869)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:650)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:843)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:317)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:127)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:115)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:112)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:169)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilterInternal(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:158)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:206)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:121)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter.doFilterInternal(CsrfFilter.java:124)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:66)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:106)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:214)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:177)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262)
    org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:121)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
root cause

org.springframework.transaction.TransactionSystemException: Could not commit JPA transaction; nested exception is javax.persistence.RollbackException: Transaction marked as rollbackOnly
    org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:521)
    org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:761)
    org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:730)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:485)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:291)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:655)
    it.webgate.controller.AjaxController$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$df5721c1_2.plantDelete(<generated>)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:136)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:832)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:743)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:961)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:895)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:967)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:869)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:650)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:843)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:317)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:127)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:115)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:112)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:169)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilterInternal(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:158)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:206)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:121)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter.doFilterInternal(CsrfFilter.java:124)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:66)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:106)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:214)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:177)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262)
    org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:121)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
root cause

javax.persistence.RollbackException: Transaction marked as rollbackOnly
    org.hibernate.jpa.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:58)
    org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:512)
    org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:761)
    org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:730)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:485)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:291)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:655)
    it.webgate.controller.AjaxController$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$df5721c1_2.plantDelete(<generated>)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:136)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:832)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:743)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:961)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:895)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:967)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:869)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:650)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:843)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:317)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:127)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:115)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:112)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:169)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilterInternal(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:158)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:206)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:121)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter.doFilterInternal(CsrfFilter.java:124)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:66)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:106)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:214)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:177)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262)
    org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:121)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
```

Comment: As expected... The record is deleted on commit not when calling `entity manager.remove`. So the `delete` method would have already returned.

Comment: I added commit and transaction but it's same.

Comment: That won't change a thing. Spring already started a transaction. You could add a flush but that is kind of a bad idea imho.

Comment: well actually if you see the exception is of type `DataIntegrityViolationException` , which you are not catching it at all , so which is exactly your issue ?

Comment: I want to capture the exception and not get the 500 error is clearly indicated in the question. i change code.

Comment: If the goal is to catch a persistence exception early, then calling `entityManager.flush()` after the removal pretty much is what you need to do.

Comment: wow wait  , just a few seconds ago it looked like you were handling the transaction by yourself. In your current code , how you get the `entityManager` instance ? is it configured by spring , and the transaction manager as well?

Comment: @Gimby nothing change

Comment: @AntJavaDev 
It was a test

Comment: I see negative votes the question. I do not see the need. At the moment the problem has no solution. I do not think is in violation of the guidelines of the site. Guadagante points to put negative votes?

Comment: then you have the issue mentioned by @M.Deinum ,  the exception will be raised and handled by the spring proxy bean when committing the transaction , not when calling `entityManager.remove`. Could you post the full code of the class which is calling the `public void delete(Integer id)` method

Comment: @ciro then I don't really believe the entityManager.remove() is the one tripping an exception. But because you provide only a very narrow view of te error you're getting, without any stacktrace, I can only guess.

Comment: @AntJavaDev i post controller code. it's rest controller type of spring mvc application

Comment: wow , first of all what property is this `plantDao.getMessage()`?Is `plantDao` a stateless or a stateful bean? Secondly, why are you directly wiring the DAO layer in the Controller , and bypassing the Service layer? In that way Spring has wrapped the controller's method two times both for the MVC and for the Transaction Advisor, not quite sure if this gives the expected result. Anyway try to make a Service class,wire there the DAO and put the `@Transactional` on the Service class , and then wire the service class to the controller. Also why are you wiring the `EntityManager` at the controller?

Comment: @Gimby i post full stack trace

Comment: @AntJavaDev Ok I removed the annotation transactional and now I capture the exception. So the problem was ...?

Comment: ............ok go over again and read Spring documentation regarding `@Transactional`. Now that you removed the annotation , it means that in case of an exception , the transaction will not be rollbacked , if you dont explicitly handle it

Comment: @AntJavaDev thanks. if you post solution as answer i sign it.

Comment: ok ill post the proper config

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First Introduce the Service Layer , create a class like below , and place it in a package that is being scanned by Spring.

```
@Service
public class PlantService{

    @Resource
    private  PlantDao plantDao;

    @Transactional(rollbackFor = Exception.class)
    public Object plantDelete(Integer id){
        Map<String,Object> out = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        plantDao.delete(id);
        out.put("status",plantDao.getStatus());
        out.put("message",plantDao.getMessage());
        return out;
    }

}
```

Then change your controller class like :

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/ajax/")
@Component
public class AjaxController {

    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(AjaxController.class);


    @Resource
    private  PlantService plantService;

    @Resource
    private Configuration configuration;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/plant-delete", headers = "Accept=application/json")
    public Object plantDelete(@RequestParam Integer id){
        Map<String,Object> out;
        try
        {
            out=  plantService.delete(id);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            out.put("status",false);
            out.put("message","Delete Failed");
        }
        return out;
    }

}
```